# Media query not working on Mobile . Css

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

I know it's a long going one, but i have a media query for landscape. It works fine on chrome emulator etc.. But when i look it on iPhone and Android, the media query is not kicking in.

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) and (max-height: 414px) {
    #flip-container {
        display: block;
    }
    .text {
        display: none;
    }
    .nav {
        display: none;
    }
    .logo {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you specify

```
@media screen and
min-width: XXX px and 
max-width: XXX px and 
and (orientation:landscape) {
//your css code

}
```

And for iPhone , i use XCODE for simulator and then test there to check if there is any issue with it. 
Sometimes, most of the times, chrome emulator doesn't work right.

As well as, if u are trying to target specified iPad, u can use iPad media queries.

Comment: Thanks yeah , i had to specify the max-width and min width. it worked now. Oh chrome emulator makes things harder.

Comment: Welcome. Keep Coding !!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the max-height. Try it with **max-width**.

Comment: #flip-container {
        display: block important ;
    }    make it working on android but iphone still now working